How to get Azure Advisor scores from azure resource graph explorer?
How to get Azure Advisor scores from azure resource graph explorer?
In particular I am looking for the Cost, Reliability, Operational Excellence and Performance total scores.

I know I can get the security score like this:
SecurityResources
| where type == 'microsoft.security/securescores'
| where subscriptionId == "MY-SUBSCRIPTION-ID"
| project percentageScore=properties.score.percentage

I also know it is possible to query the score through the Management REST API like this  - but I really want to avoid that.

Kindly check this-  Query for Advisor data in Resource Graph Explorer (Azure Resource Graph)
and try this example once-
AdvisorResources | where type == 'microsoft.advisor/recommendations' | extend category=tostring(properties.category), impact=tostring(properties.impact), score=properties.score | summarize count() by category, impact, score it should return the count of recommendations by category, impact, and score. give it a try

@Arko that does not work. The properties column has category and impact but not a score.
What I am looking for is also a total score, not a score per recommendation.

the score property does not exist directly in the properties.extendedProperties  as a workaround you can use the following KQL query the query starts by filtering resources of type microsoft.advisor/recommendations. then categorizes score like this   High impact recommendations are given a score of 1.0.  Medium impact recommendations are given a score of 0.5.   Low impact recommendations are given a score of 0.1 and then summarizes the average impact scores for each category. See if this works for you.

OK, I see where you are going with this.  How did you come up with the impact values?
I think Microsoft calculates the score completely differently. Now I am guessing, but I think each recommendation comes with a score, based on an impact and number of affected resources. Then they sum all the scores for the and calculates the total score for the category. But that is not all. If you take a look at the screenshot then some scores are 100% event though there is a medium recommendation. The right solution  cannot be to calculate the score yourself. There must be a way to look it up.

Values I chose myself manually for demonstration purpose to assign numerical weights to different impact levels. I was looking around regarding the same and found Azure offers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/advisor/ for this. Using KQL query, this is what I was able to get apart from the one which I already shared above.

So unfortunately it is not possible to get Azure Advisor scores from azure resource graph.
Right now the best way to do this is th call the Azure Management REST API.
Here's an example. I've left out the authentication. You need to get a token and add itto the Authentication header.:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SUBSCRIPTION_ID}/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/advisorScore?api-version=2023-01-01

